# Override Plugin Globally

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making a custom `jquery` plugin that simply manipulates the `css` on a page, after it loads.

Basically, as I loop through a few elements, I search for things like emails, Dates, etc...

Example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var pluginActive = true;

   $("td.groupofcells").changeCSS({
       pluginActive: pluginActive, // defaulted to true anyways
       lookFor:{ "emails", "dates" },
       class:"bolder_bigger"
   });

   $("span.lookforspans").changeCSS({
       pluginActive: pluginActive,
       lookFor:{ "img" },
       class:"bgborder"
   });

   $("img.myicon").changeCSS({
       pluginActive: pluginActive,
       class:"disappear"
   });

});
</script>
```

I'm sure most of you can clearly see what I'm doing.

My option: **pluginActive**, is either true or false.
If I specify **false** then my plugin simply ignores the instance, which is working great.

Now I've found moments that I want every **pluginActive** automatically to FALSE.

Is there a way I can globally set Every **pluginActive** to be **false** for all of my instances, without having to change each individually?

At the moment I'm manually putting conditions (in PHP).  But I'm curious if there's a more all-encompassing method, without omitting the `<script>` from the header, nor creating a PHP condition.  (I'd like to use less PHP in this case if possible)

Comment: Just edit plugin js & change default variable value simple

Comment: Yes, have your plugin expose it's `defaults` in a way that can be modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question with a more simple solution that I completely didn't consider.

I added my Edits above, but in a nutshell:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var pluginActive = true;
</script>
```

This is the easiest globalized way I could imagine.
Honestly, I was thinking of a more abstracted way to affect a plugin, and made it harder on myself.